# Generate Controller and Model

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie with Laravel and I played around laravel 4(Beta version). I want to know how to generate Controller and Model by command line use `php artisan`. But I don't know how to do them.

Comment: Hi Sophy, what happens when you type `php artisan help:commands` into your terminal?

Comment: There is documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers

Comment: @Laurence those are for Laravel 3.2, AFAIK the docs for 4.0 will be released with the beta.

Sophy: Laravel 4 is still pre-beta.  It's going to be tough to find support for it.  Taylor Otwell has said they hope to release it this week, with full documentation.

Comment: @ChrisMoll: This week? really? Cannot wait for it :D

Comment: @AkhyarAmarullah Yea, hopefully today or tomorrow according to [twitter](https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/289139602520936449).  [Here](https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/288330393214660608) is where he said it will come with full documentation.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See this video: http://youtu.be/AjQ5e9TOZVk?t=1m45s
You can do `php artisan list` to view all commands, 
The command for generating REST-ful controllers is `controller:make`
You can view the usage with: `php artisan help make:controller`

Comment: What about creating models...??

Comment: Will be in Laravel 5: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/cb1142897be11c59b374340fa0826408b13b9f55
php artisan make:model

Comment: the php artisan list is actually so handy! a really good reference for when forgetful peeps like me get back into personal projects

Answer (score 38):

**Laravel 5**

The other answers are great for Laravel 4 but [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) is here! We now have the ability to generate all kinds of stuff by default. Run `php artisan help` to view all artisan commands. Here are all of the `make` commands:

```
make
  make:command         Create a new command class
  make:console         Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller      Create a new resource controller class
  make:event           Create a new event class
  make:middleware      Create a new middleware class
  make:migration       Create a new migration file
  make:model           Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:provider        Create a new service provider class
  make:request         Create a new form request class
```

**Note:** we no longer use *item*:make. Instead we now have make:*item*.

Run `php artisan help make:item` to see what you can pass it. For instance `php artisan help make:migration` shows that we need to pass it the migration name but we can also pass it `--create=""` or `--table=""` to specify the table name to create or modify respectively. Run `php artisan make:migration create_articles_table --create="articles"` to generate the articles table. Moreover, generating models takes care of generating the migration for that model. Follow the naming conventions and it will be pluralized it for the migration.

Comment: Could you tell me how to make a controller in a sub directory? I tried `php artisan make:controller Orders\OrderController` but it created the controller in the `app\Http\Controllers` directory. **Never mind** I was using the back slash instead of forward slash like `php artisan make:controller Orders/OrderController`

Answer (score 35):

Thank you @user1909426, I can found solution by `php artisan list` it will list all command that was used on L4. It can create controller only not Model. I follow this command to generate controller.

```
php artisan controller:make [Name]Controller
```

On Laravel 5, the command has changed:

```
php artisan make:controller [Name]Controller
```

**Note:** [Name] name of controller

Comment: The edit made by @user3789181 is incorrect. The question is about Laravel 4 and Sophy's original answer address Laravel 4. This edit to the code will not work in Laravel 4 but the text preceding it says it addressed Laravel 4. The answer should either be edited to say it only works in Laravel 5 or it should be reverted to the original answer instead of the edit. I attempted to edit it back.

Comment: This answer no longer makes sense because the edit made it incompatible with Laravel 4.

Answer (score 18):

Make **resource controller** with **Model**.

`php artisan make:controller PostController --model=Post`

Answer (score 13):

For generate Model , controller with resources and migration best command is:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -m -cr
```

Answer (score 6):

laravel artisan does not support default model and view generation. check this provider https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators to generate models, views, seeder etc.

Answer (score 5):

**Make model , Controller by**

```
php artisan make:model Customer -mc
```

**Make model , Controller with Resource**

```
php artisan make:model Customer -mcr
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a plain controller file like

```
php artisan make:controller --plain <controller name>
```

Answer (score 2):

Models:

```
php artisan krlove:generate:model Videos --table-name=videos
```

Comment: While this may help out OP, a good answer typically requires no further clarification. Please tell us something more about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create with Resource Method

```
php artisan make:controller --resource ControllerName  --model=ModelName
```

Use It With a path

```
php artisan make:controller --resource path/ControllerName  --model=ModelName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
make:model {{SingularName}}
```

e.g

```
make:model Video
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:controller --resource Backend/API/DemoController --model=Demo
```

Answer (score 0):

See all Available Controller : You can do PHP artisan list to view all commands

For help: PHP artisan help make:controller

```
php artisan make:controller MyControllerName
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can generate controller and model individually and together also.

1. create Controller

   **php artisan make:controller Controllername**
2. Create Model

   **php artisan make:model Modelname**
3. Create controller and model together

   **php artisan make:controller Controllername --model=Modelname**

**Note:** Please make habit to create controller and model name capitalize (First letter capital letter).